# What would be the Latin word for an entry in a dictionary or an encyclopedia?

Tags: word-choice

> [**entry**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entry) An item in a list, such as an article in a dictionary or encyclopedia. — Wiktionary

What would be the best Latin word to translate *entry* in this context?
The [online dictionary](https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php?parola=entry) I use don't give any result.

**Edit.** [Smith & All](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=sh1457) give “caput, capitis” for “A clause in a law, treaty, etc.” but the meaning is a bit different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In New Latin lexicography, the word for an entry in a dictionary or an encylopedia is ***vōx,***  so "see the entry *porcus*" would be *(vidē) **sub vōce** 'porcus',* abbreviated as *s.v. porcus.*  This abbreviation found its way into English as well as other European languages. Note that some sources alternatively interpret this abbreviation as *"sub **verbō**",* but based on the use of the latter word this seems less likely, although theoretically I don't see a reason why it couldn't be used in this meaning. *vōx* in Latin stands for a combination of speech sounds with a certain meaning, regardless of its part of speech. The Oxford Latin Dictionary, which considers only classical usage, lists it as '10 (gram.) A word' (2nd ed., p. 2320).

The first occurrence of *sub vōce* with roughly that meaning appears to be in [Manilius' Astronomica](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/manilius-astronomica/1977/pb_LCL469.167.xml): *propriā melius **sub vōce** notantur* ('is better expressed by the native word'). Apart from this, the phrase *[tremuit] sub vōce* is found [in Lucan](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/lucan-civil_war/1928/pb_LCL220.265.xml) to mean 'trembled before his words, at his voice', and [Lucretius uses](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/lucretius-de_rerum_natura/1924/pb_LCL181.339.xml) *sub verbō* to mean 'at [her] word, i.e. at once', where *verbum* means 'command'.

Comment: Thank you. The abbreviation does indeed seem to be well attested but the word itself, in the dictionaries I have, only refers to "voice" or "saying". This is an interesting case

Comment: @Laravel The Oxford Latin Dictionary lists it as meaning 10 (gram.) A word.

Comment: @Laravel Hey, I've edited my answer to add some ancient support for this usage of *vōx* and to contrast it with its theoretical alternative, *verbum.* If this ends up reassuring you that this is *the* expression to use, please consider accepting my answer. It seems to be well-established in New Latin lexicography and I don't believe there exist any alternatives for it, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 7):

Salve. I agree that *caput* is not the right word here. A quick look in Cassell's Latin Dictionary gives "entry" as *nomen*. This use, however, is for debts in an account book, therefore this is not the right word for this. A look in the [Lexicon Morganianum](http://lexicon.paideiainstitute.org/search/latin?search=entry) gave *lemma, lemmatis n.* It is a Greek loanword from *λῆμμα*. The word, Latinised, means things like "a theme, matter, subject, **contents**" (L&S). The Greek seems to mean "anything received, income, . . . gain, etc." (Middle Liddell). I think *lemma* would be the right word here.

*Lemma* is also used in English. In English, it means about the same as the Latin: "a dictionary entry" and "the argument or subject of a literary composition, prefixed as a heading or title" (OED).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a good idea indeed. I don't know if there is a purely Latin solution but if not I will use lemma

Comment: The thing is, the use you're suggesting isn't found in Latin, [not even in New Latin](http://nlw.renaessancestudier.org/words/start.htm). You're backporting an international Graecism into Latin, but the word doesn't have that meaning even in Greek, and is already used in Latin with a different meaning, [including New Latin](http://mateo.uni-mannheim.de/camenaref/hofmann/hof2/s0780a.html). D. Morgan's Silva isn't a proper dictionary but an informal collection of translation ideas; it doesn't attest usage but gives tentative suggestions that don't find their way into the Adumbratio.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian Interesting, I did not know that. What dictionary would you recommend  for Neo- and contemporary Latin? Is the *Adumbratio* reliable? What about, Traupman’s conversational Latin? I don’t think he gives sources.

Comment: Turning that into a question was a good move, I'll write an answer there later if there will still be need for it. The bottom line is that none of them is fool-proof, and the only dictionary I trust is my own brain :-)))

Comment: Gratiās tibi agō

Comment: Lemma has its own meaning in multiple academic fields too. Mathematics ("minor, easily proven thing, used in more comolex proofs") and botany (some kind of plant part if I recall correctly) come to mind.